# Designing a database for storing tables with an arbitrary numbers of fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to build a leads aggregating system. In general what the system would do is storing the data a client sends from a landing page (name, phone, email etc).

The interesting part is that I don't know ahead what fields each landing page will contain. So, one landing page might need `name`, `phone` and `email`, while other landing page will gather `email` and `num_of_kids`. I will also need to save the caption for the field somehow - because I need to display `num_of_kids` as `Number of Children`. I was thinking of simply storing the whole thing in one field as a JSON object, but that felt cheap and wrong (and it would suck sorting and selecting it).

I'm open to suggestions and workaround ideas (the solution doesn't have to be strictly MySQL).

*EDIT: I've decided to use MongoDB for that project. At the moment it looks like one of the best decisions I've made this year.*

Comment: See [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: Did you look into mongodb or some other document DB?

Comment: @MarkoJovanovic actually I finally did, and that's what I'm gonna use. You should've put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with schema-less, NoSQL database like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)

Further reading:
[NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)

P.S. Good luck with it, and have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#store minimal required data as the lead
CREATE TABLE leads (
   leads_id SERIAL,
   name TINYTEXT
)

#Store the rest of the data as key-value pair
CREATE TABLE leads_data (
   leads_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   field_name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
   field_value TINYTEXT NOT NULL
);
```

or you can store the field names in one table, and the value in a 3th

```
CREATE TABLE leads_fields (
   leads_field_id SERIAL,
   field_name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
   field_type TINYTEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE leads_data (
   leads_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   leads_field_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   field_value TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(leads_id, leads_field_id)
);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that impact performance? When I have to get search 5-6 tables for each lead? (I'll have to also search for the landing page owner, and the banner it came from etc)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered storing the variable form data in an XML field? Then you could use `ExtractValue` with XPath to get the values

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help me?

Comment: It's a bit like your idea of storing the data as JSON, but with selecting and filtering abilities.